# Hibernate generate old query after column renaming

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've renamed column in my database (from configuration_SYSTEM_ID to SYSTEM_ID), and added AttributeOverride annotation to my AbstractSubConfiguration class. But hibernate ignore this annotation and continue generate queries with old column names (configuration_SYSTEM_ID instead of SYSTEM_ID).

My classes looks like this:

AbstractSubConfiguration.java

```
       @MappedSuperclass
        @IdClass(Configuration.class)
        public class AbstractSubConfiguration implements Dto, Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -6271877313478924753L;

            @Id
            @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @AttributeOverride(name = "systemId", column = @Column(name = "SYSTEM_ID"))
            private Configuration configuration;

            public AbstractSubConfiguration() {
                super();
            }

            public AbstractSubConfiguration(final Configuration configuration) {
                super();
                this.configuration = configuration;
            }

            @XmlTransient
            public final Configuration getConfiguration() {
                return configuration;
            }

            public final void setConfiguration(final Configuration configuration) {
                this.configuration = configuration;
            }

        }
```

Configuration.java

```
    Entity(name = "CONFIGURATION")
    public class Configuration implements Dto, Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6601197795258837065L;

        @EmbeddedId
        private ConfigurationId configurationId;

        @Column(name = "CONFIGURATION_NAME")
        private String configurationName;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "configuration", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private BasicConfiguration basicConfiguration;
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "configuration", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private AdvancedConfiguration advancedConfiguration;

.....


...
}
```

ConfigurationId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class ConfigurationId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5123943430808049180L;

    private SystemId systemId;
    @Column(name = "CONFIGURATION_ID")
    private int configurationId;

    public ConfigurationId(final SystemId systemId, final int configurationId) {
        super();
        this.systemId = systemId;
        this.configurationId = configurationId;
    }
    ....

    ....
}
```

And as a result I have an error  2695 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Unknown column 'tes0_.configuration_SYSTEM_ID' in 'field list'

Comment: have you tried re-building your project?

Comment: @MohitKanwar yes of course

Comment: where is your `systemId` in `Configuration`?

Comment: @alexey it is embedded in ConfigurationId class

Comment: see edit section in my asnwer may be it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it in this way:

```
       @MappedSuperclass
        @IdClass(Configuration.class)
        public class AbstractSubConfiguration implements Dto, Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -6271877313478924753L;

            @Id
            @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "SYSTEM_ID", referencedColumnName = "SYSTEM_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "configuration_CONFIGURATION_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONFIGURATION_ID")})            
private Configuration configuration;


...


....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From doc  [@AttributeOverride](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html)

> java.lang.String  name
>             (Required) The name of the property whose mapping is being overridden if property-based access is being used, or the name of the
>   field if field-based access is used.

In your mapping I don't see `systemId` property instead I see `configurationId` property

**Edit**

Accordance your editing name in `@AttributeOverride` should be `configuration.systemId`

See example from [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) with zipcode:

```
@Embeddable public class Address {
        protected String street;
        protected String city;
        protected String state;
        @Embedded protected Zipcode zipcode;
    }

    @Embeddable public class Zipcode {
        protected String zip;
        protected String plusFour;
    }

    @Entity public class Customer {
        @Id protected Integer id;
        protected String name;
        @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name="state",
                               column=@Column(name="ADDR_STATE")),
            @AttributeOverride(name="zipcode.zip",
                               column=@Column(name="ADDR_ZIP"))
        })
        @Embedded protected Address address;
        ...
    }
```